# C/C++ prevent macro expansion inside macro

Tags: c++, macros

Let's consider:

```
#define PARENTHESIS1 (
#define PARENTHESIS2 )
#define macro_test_0(arg1, arg2) int arg1 arg2
#define macro_test_1(arg1, arg2) macro_test_0(arg1, arg2)

macro_test_0(PARENTHESIS1, PARENTHESIS2 ;) //->works fine
macro_test_1(PARENTHESIS1, PARENTHESIS2 ;) //doesn't work
```

For macro_test_1 I have error message: "Macro argument mismatch", "Too few arguments provided to function-like invocation method", "Use of undeclared identifier 'macro_test_0' ".

Thing is, for macro_test_0, example gives:

```
int ( ) ;
```

which is ok, but macro_test_1 example gives (if I'm correct):

```
macro_test_0((,) ;)
```

which is obviously wrong. I'd like arg1 and arg2 of the macro to prevent expansion, in order to keep:

```
macro_test0(PARENTHESIS1, PARENTHESIS2 ;)
```

I guess it's related to macro expansion order, but is there a way or trick to achieve this ? I tried several things such as artificial (ie useless) concatenation of arguments to delay expansion during macro invocation but without success.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple solution. For advanced preprocessor stuff, you should generally look at [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) first. Perhaps it will have a different solution for your larger problem.

Comment: Multi-level macro replacement, which depends on order of macro replacement, _and_ also macro's which expand to parentheses (which are significant in macro syntax)? Problems are to be expected. Why do you need this? In C++, there's almost always a better solution.

Comment: Angew > I've been looking into boost preprocessor, but couldn't find a solution among the available macros. Open parentheses as arguments look totally cursed..

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which compiler or IDE u use.

but for visual studio 2012: both line generate same code after preprocessing

```
int ( ) ; 
int ( ) ;
```

for vs:

'src file' property -> C/C++/Preprocessor -> preprocess to a file

option will output code after preprocessing to a file

GCC have similar compile options.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.1.1, clang-503.0.40 . I tried -fpch-preprocess as compiler option, which is equivalent to your option in vs I think, but it dosent' work. I'm still on it, might be a good clue.

Comment: I can't understand why it's working in VS. The same result appears for clang and gcc as in the first post. Why would VS preprocessor (Ming ? not sure) change the substitution/expansion order